# Access Denied Error When Trying to Run AppEngine Cloud SQL application from Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create an appengine application with a Cloud SQL database connection in Eclipse, and am getting a *java.security.AccessControlException* access denied error when I try to run the application.

I am using version 1.9.17 of the google appengine plugin, and version 4.4 of the google plugin for Eclipse.

My code is based on the approach outlined at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/

I have tried to run the application using a number of different approaches, but this makes no difference.

1. Using AppEngine Server in Eclipse - the error occurs when starting the
   appengine server
2. Running using the Maven appengine:devserver goal - the appengine starts with no error, error occurs when trying to load http://localhost:8080/guestbook.jsp

**Code extract- guestbook.jsp**

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
     SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
     url = "jdbc:google:mysql://instance:datastore/guestbook";
} else {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/guestbook";
}
```

**Code extract - GuestbookServlet.java**

```
try {
  if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
      SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
    url = "jdbc:google:mysql://instance:datastore/guestbook";
  } else {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/guestbook";
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return;
}
```

**Error**

```
[INFO] java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc")
[INFO]     at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
[INFO]     at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
[INFO]     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
[INFO]     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1525)
[INFO]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:114)
[INFO]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
[INFO]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[INFO]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
[INFO]     at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:463)
[INFO]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:568)
[INFO]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
[INFO]     at org.apache.jsp.guestbook_jsp._jspService(guestbook_jsp.java:77)
[INFO]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
[INFO]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[INFO]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
[INFO]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
[INFO]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
[INFO]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
[INFO]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]     at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
[INFO]     at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Do you have a local mysql server installed and running, with the userid you're using for your local GAE devel server enabled for password-less connection?  I believe that's what `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/guestbook"` is trying to use.  The sample you point to, commenting `// Local MySQL instance to use during development.`, uses `"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?user=root"` (it doesn't explicitly say, but I assume does require, that `root` be allowed password-less connection in said local MySQL instance).

Comment: I do have a local mysql server installed, in terms of the connection string I ammended it from the example so I can pass in a password using the following line   'Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(  url,
          "root", "password");'

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me.
I removed the appengine related jar files that were manually present in the WEB-INF\lib folder.
In the Build Path, I added the AppEngine SDK as a Library dependency.

This solved the issue for me.

Guess the problem is the conflicting jars when both the SDK and the individual jars are both added to build path!